# Include requests saved in file in soapUI project

Tags: soapui, test-suite

I have a catalog with my soap requests and I want to reuse them for building a test suite.
I tried using ENTITY definitions but couldn't make it work, while using `xi:include` for the piece of code I want to include seems soapUI doesn't recognize it.

My actual project has the following structure:

```
<con:soapui-project>

    <con:interface >
        <con:endpoints>
            <con:endpoint>http://localhost/GestionePreventiviRemoteImpl/GestionePreventiviService_v1</con:endpoint>
        </con:endpoints>

        <con:operation isOneWay="false" action="" name="aggiornaPreventivo" bindingOperationName="aggiornaPreventivo" >
            <con:settings/>
        </con:operation>

        <con:operation isOneWay="false" action="" name="creaPreventivo" bindingOperationName="creaPreventivo" >
            <con:settings/>
        </con:operation>

        <con:operation isOneWay="false" action="" name="recuperaPreventivo" bindingOperationName="recuperaPreventivo">
            <con:settings/>
        </con:operation>
    </con:interface>

    <con:testSuite name="GestioneServicePortBinding TestSuite">
        <con:testCase name="aggiornaPreventivo TestCase">
            <con:testStep name="aggiornaPreventivo">
                <con:config>
                    <con:interface>GestioneServicePortBinding</con:interface>
                    <con:operation>aggiornaPreventivo</con:operation>
                    <con:request name="aggiornaPreventivo">
                        <con:endpoint>http://localhost/GestionePreventiviRemoteImpl/GestionePreventiviService_v1</con:endpoint>

                        <con:request>
                            <![CDATA[
                            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://simulatore.Prodotto.be.service.bmed.it/v1">
                               <soapenv:Header/>
                               <soapenv:Body>
                                  <v1:aggiornaPreventivo>
                                     <input>
                                        <aggiornaPreventivoDTO>
                                           <codPrev>1001</codPrev>
                                           <codCliente>205</codCliente>
                                           .....
                                        </aggiornaPreventivoDTO>
                                     </input>
                                  </v1:aggiornaPreventivo>
                               </soapenv:Body>
                            </soapenv:Envelope>
                            ]]>
                        </con:request>
                    </con:request>
                </con:config>
            </con:testStep>
        </con:testCase>
    </con:testSuite>

</con:soapui-project>
```

And what I need is to include the request in the test case in order to handle input parameters outside the testsuite. So something like:

```
<con:testStep name="aggiornaPreventivo">
    <con:config>
        <con:interface>GestioneServicePortBinding</con:interface>
        <con:operation>aggiornaPreventivo</con:operation>
        <con:request name="aggiornaPreventivo">
            <con:endpoint>http://localhost/GestionePreventiviRemoteImpl/GestionePreventiviService_v1</con:endpoint>
            <con:request>
                <xi:include href="aggiornaPreventivoRequest.xml" parse="xml" xpointer="title"/>
            </con:request>
        </con:request>
    </con:config>
</con:testStep>
```

Where aggiornaPreventivoRequest.xml has the content like:

```
<v1:aggiornaPreventivo>
    <input>
        <aggiornaPreventivoDTO>
           <codPrev>1001</codPrev>
           <codCliente>205</codCliente>
           .....
        </aggiornaPreventivoDTO>
    </input>
</v1:aggiornaPreventivo>
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can use `<include>` from `http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude` in SOAPUI, however if you want to control the node values of your request outside the request itself you can use properties.

You can add the properties on `project`, `testSuite`, `testCase`, `testStep` level and so on, to use it directly in your request you have to use the follow notation depends on the level where you define your properties. From [SOAPUI documentation](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html):

> `${#Project#yourProperty}` - references a Project property(Reference properties across a particular SoapUI project)
>
> `${#TestSuite#yourProperty}` - references a TestSuite property in the containing TestSuite
>
> `${#TestCase#yourProperty}` - references a TestCase property in the containing TestCase
>
> `${TestStep name#yourProperty}` - references a TestStep property

For example if you add the property on the testSuite:

```
<v1:aggiornaPreventivo>
    <input>
        <aggiornaPreventivoDTO>
           <codPrev>${#TestSuite#codPrevValue}</codPrev>
           <codCliente>${#TestSuite#codClienteValue}</codCliente>
           .....
        </aggiornaPreventivoDTO>
    </input>
</v1:aggiornaPreventivo>
```

If you don't know how to add properties to your project take a look at [this](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html).

There is also another possibility if you're really interested to send a request from a local file you can also use a `groovy` testStep with the follow code to send a request from specific file location:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.DefaultedHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// the directory with your xml requests
def directory = new File("/tmp/myRequests/")
// for each file in the directory
directory.eachFile{ file -> 
    // create the request
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://your_endpoint")
    def reqEntity = new FileEntity(file,"application/xml");
     post.setEntity(reqEntity)
    // make the post and get the response
    def responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler()
    def responseBody = httpclient.execute(post, responseHandler)
    log.info responseBody
};
```

Hope this helps,